# Complete matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Which of the following are complete eigenvalues (by complete,
>   corresponding eigenspace has the same dimension as its multiplicity)
>   for the indicated matrix? What is the dimension of the associated
>   eigenspace?
>
> a.) $\pmatrix{2&1\\1&2}$
>
> b.) $\pmatrix{-1&-4&-4\\0&-1&0\\0&4&3}$

- For a, I got the eigenvalues of $\lambda = 3,1$ and the corresponding eigenvectors are $v = \pmatrix{1\\1}$, $v_1 = \pmatrix{1\\-1}$ but the answer says it is complete and has $dim = 1$ with basis of $\pmatrix{1\\1}$.
- For b, I got the eigenvalues of $\lambda = -1,-1,3$, its corresponding eigenvectors is $\pmatrix{0\\-1\\1}$ for $\lambda = -1$ and $\pmatrix{1\\0\\1}$ for $\lambda = 3$ but then the $dim = 2$ with basis $\pmatrix{1\\0\\0}$, $\pmatrix{0\\-1\\1}$ and it is complete. How did they get that?

> Also, why does $\pmatrix{1&3\\3&1}$ (which has eigenvalues of -2,4 and
>   eigenvectors $\pmatrix{-1\\1}$, $\pmatrix{1\\1}$) form a basis in
>   $\mathbb{R^2}$ and in $\mathbb{C^2}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(A) Let me check what you're doing for eigenvals/eigenvecs...

- $det\pmatrix{{2-\lambda}&1\\1&{2-\lambda}}=(2-\lambda)^2-1=\lambda^2-4\lambda+3=(\lambda-3)(\lambda-1)=0$. So you are correct, $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=3$.
- $M-\lambda_1I_2=\pmatrix{{1}&1\\1&{1}}$ which leads to this equation $x_1+x_2=0$ for both which means this eigenvector $v_1=\pmatrix{1\\-1}$.
- $M-\lambda_2 I_2=\pmatrix{{-1}&1\\1&{-1}}$ which leads to the equation $x_1-x_2=0$ for both which means this eigenvector $v_2=\pmatrix{1\\1}$. Everything you did is correct.

Perhaps what you are confused on is associating the eigenvector with an eigenspace. The dimension of $v_1$ and $v_2$ are both $1$ which corresponds to the multiplicity of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ which are both $1$ $\Rightarrow$ complete.

**Summary:** Correspondence

- $dim(v_1)=1$ and $mult(\lambda_1)=1$
- $dim(v_2)=1$ and $mult(\lambda_2)=1$

Which implies completeness.

---

(B) Probably similar confusion. Again correct, $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=-1$ and $\lambda_3=3$.

- $M-\lambda_1 I_3=\pmatrix{0&-4&-4\\0&0&0\\0&4&4}$ which leads to the system of equations $x_2+x_3=0$. But you are forgetting that $x_1$ can be anything. So your eigenvectors for $\lambda_1$ are $\pmatrix{0\\-1\\1}$ AND $\pmatrix{1\\0\\0}$. So the dimension of the eigenspace is $2$ (the span of $\pmatrix{0\\-1\\1}, \pmatrix{1\\0\\0}$) which corresponds to the multiplicity of $\lambda_1$ which is $2$ since it appears twice.

Also you are correct for $dim (v_3)=1$ corresponding to $mult (\lambda_3)=1$ $\Rightarrow$ complete.

If you want to do a little more study on evals, evecs and espaces, [check this link out](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P19tjWwPiSE).

---

(C) Your eigenvecs are $\pmatrix{-1\\1}$ and $\pmatrix{1\\1}$. If you can show that the standard basis for $\Bbb R^2$ which is $\pmatrix{1\\0}$ and $\pmatrix{0\\1}$ is within your eigenvecs then you show that it is a basis. Notice

- $\frac 1 2 \pmatrix{-1\\1}+\frac 1 2 \pmatrix{1\\1} = \pmatrix{0\\1}$
- $\frac {-1} 2 \pmatrix{-1\\1}+\frac 1 2 \pmatrix{1\\1} = \pmatrix{1\\0}$

So since you can form the standard basis using just a linear combination of your eigenvectors, these eigenvectors also serve as a basis for $\Bbb R^2$.

$\Bbb C^2$ is basically the same, as you can have your scalars be in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks a lot!!! Last question, for part c. for $\mathbb{C^n}$ how is it a scalar multiple of it? What will make a basis both in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\mathbb{C^n}$? Also, what will make the basis in $\mathbb{R^n}$ but not in $\mathbb{C^n}$ and vice-versa?

Comment: For $\Bbb C$ it depends **how** you are looking at your basis. If you are looking over the complex numbers or over the real numbers. The standard basis for $\Bbb R^n$ over $\Bbb R$ is the same as the standard basis for $\Bbb C^n$ over $\Bbb C$, i.e. since you can manufacture anything in $\Bbb C^2$ with $$x_1\pmatrix{0\\1}+x_2\pmatrix{0\\1}$$ where $x_1, x_2 \in \Bbb C$. Since $x_1$ and $x_2$ can be imaginary, we can produce any element in $\Bbb C^2$ with just those two basis vectors.

Comment: If you need a basis of $\Bbb C^2$ over $\Bbb R$ you will also need vectors that provide $i$ to your mix. In this case you would need $$x_1\pmatrix{1\\0}+x_2\pmatrix{0\\1}+x_3\pmatrix{i\\0}+x_4\pmatrix{0\\i}$$ where each $x_k \in \Bbb R$. Now the first two are the "real basis" and the second two are the "imaginary basis".

Comment: The "standard basis" for any field $F^n$ is usually considered to be over $F$, thus making it simply $$e_1=\pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\...}, e_2=\pmatrix{0\\1\\0\\...}, ... e_n=\pmatrix{...\\0\\0\\1}$$

Comment: Thanks for explaining that but I am still having some difficulty understanding it. For ex. why doesn't these two seperate matrix $$\pmatrix{1&-2&0\\0&-1&0\\0&-4&-1} , \pmatrix{0&0&-1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0}$$ form a basis in $\mathbb{C^n}$, but the matrix in part c does?

Comment: (Used evec/eval calculator online on both matrices.) **FIRST ONE:** I get evals $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=-1$ and $\lambda_3=1$ and eigenvectors $v_1=\pmatrix{0\\0\\1}$, $v_2=\pmatrix{0\\0\\1}$ and $v_3=\pmatrix{1\\0\\0}$. This is clearly not a basis of $\Bbb C^3$

Comment: This is where I am confused because what makes this not a basis of $\mathbb{C^n}$ but $$\pmatrix{1&3\\3&1}$$ does make it a basis of both $\mathbb{C^n}$ and $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Comment: **SECOND ONE:** I get evals $\lambda_1=1$, $\lambda_2=i$ and $\lambda_3=-i$ and eigenvectors $v_1=\pmatrix{0\\1\\0}$, $v_2=\pmatrix{1\\0\\-i}$ and $v_3=\pmatrix{1\\0\\i}$. This is not a basis of $\Bbb C^3$ over $\Bbb R$ since imaginary entries are only in the 3rd column and the first two columns are only real.

Comment: The basis for $\pmatrix{1&3\\3&1}$ can "manufacture" $\pmatrix{1\\0}$ and $\pmatrix{0\\1}$ as I show above, while the basis for $\pmatrix{1&-2&0\\0&-1&0\\0&-4&-1}$ can never "manufacture" $\pmatrix{0\\1\\0}$ since $v_1=v_2=e_3$. And when I say manufacture I mean produce through linear combination

Comment: Maybe I am having trouble understanding the concept of imagainary

Comment: Oh ok, so in order for it to be a basis in a given space then it has to be able to manufacture the identity matrix somehow?

Comment: Essentially. in $\Bbb R^3$ or $\Bbb C^3$ you must be able to manufacture $e_1$, $e_2$, and $e_3$. Those three make up the identity matrix, which is the standard basis.  (where $e_1=\pmatrix{1\\0\\0}$, $e_2=\pmatrix{0\\1\\0}$, $e_3=\pmatrix{0\\0\\1}$)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis for reference

Comment: You're very welcome!